# 'where' inside other expression

Tags: haskell

I can use `let` inside other expression.

```
foo n = (let a = True in (\x -> a)) 3

foo' n | n == 1 = let a = True in a
       | n /= 1 = False
```

But I can't do the same with `where`

```
foo n = ((\x -> a) where a = True) 3

foo' n | n == 1 = a where a = True
       | n /= 1 = False
```

> 1:20: parse error on input `where'

Is it really impossible in haskell or just my mistake?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`let` is an expression while `where` is a clause. `where` is bound to syntactic constructs, let can be used anywhere expressions can.

You could of course write it like this:

```
foo n = ((\x -> a)) 3 where a = True

foo' n | n == 1 = a
       | n /= 1 = False
       where a = True
```

or like this:

```
foo n = (\a -> (\x -> a) 3) True
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the `where` clause at the end:

```
foo n = ((\x -> a)) 3
  where a = True

foo' n | n == 1 = a
       | n /= 1 = False
  where a = True
```

The difference is that `let` is an expression, whereas `where` requires some other construct to be bound to. See [let vs where](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Let_vs._Where)

Answer (score 1):

`let ... in ...` is for introducing name bindings in an expression.

`where` is convenience syntax for giving local auxiliary definitions along with an equation. You can only use it as part of an equation (at the end), not in the middle of an arbitrary expression.

Their usage is not the same.

Comment: This is a bit inaccurate. You can have `where` clauses on local definitions in a `let` or `where`, or on the alternatives of a `case` expression, not only on top level definitions.

Comment: `where` clauses aren't limited to *top-level* definitions--they're also valid inside `let`, `where`, `instance`, or anything else that lets you write definitions in that style. (EDIT: And now I see that hammar just made the same remark. Oh well.)

Comment: @C.A.McCann Rats. I was trying to avoid saying "function definition", since such definitions aren't necessarily functions, and functions don't have to be defined with that syntax. What's the name for that definition syntax then? "Equation" I guess?

Comment: I'm too lazy to check right now, but I'd go with whatever term the Haskell Report uses. Equation sounds reasonable, though.

Answer (score 0):

The claim that `let` is an expression is a bit off, it seems to me; in a `do` block it is a statement, though we say that there it abbreviates `let ... in`.  The thing to say, I think, is

```
 let_in_ :: Statement -> Expression -> Expression
 _where_ :: Statement -> Statement  -> Statement
```

Thus the first part of a `let` is a statement and can be modified by a `where`. So for example

```
 foo n = (let a = b where b = True in (\x -> a)) 3

 bip = do 
     let a = b where b = let c = d where d = True in c
     return a
```

Similarly we can maybe say something like this:

```
 case_of_ :: Expression -> [Statement] -> Expression
```

so that e.g.

```
z x = case even x of 
   True -> d where d = x + 1
   False -> w - 1 where w = let a = x in a + 1
```